# API Jmeter create a reusable request depends on the selection of the user

Tags: json, api, rest, jmeter, request

Does anyone know how simulate scenario below and write on a reusable format? Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Example I have this userdefine variable name "userInput" if user tries to enter these following metrics it should generate the corresponding request as well. Note variable name may varries from time to time depends on user selection.

Scenario 1 - **network,cpu,process**

{
"networkMetric": "network.json",
"cpuMetric": "cpu_json",
"processMetric": "process_json"
}

Scenario 2 - **cpu,process**

{
"cpuMetric": "cpu_json",
"processMetric": "process_json"
}

Scenario 3 -**network,cpu**

{
"networkMetric": "network.json",
"cpuMetric": "cpu_json"
}

Scenario 4 - **process**

{
"processMetric": "process_json"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the "request" using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) (i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)) and the following code:

```
def payload = [:]
vars.get('userInput').split(',').each { metric ->
    payload.put(metric + 'Metric', metric + '_json')
}

vars.put('request', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

you will be able to refer the generated request body as `${request}` where required and the body will depend on the `${userInput}` variable value.

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Can you please show your body payload or Http Request for this demo? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's `${request}`

Comment: Thanks already got your demo, what if my body data is different from the request that I'll be using example this scenario how can I make this variable/reusable?


{
    "NetworkMetric": "network_json",
    "ProcessInfoMetric": "process_json",
    "CpuMetric": "cpu_metric_json"
}