# Jmeter customize request depends on users selection

Tags: json, api, rest, jmeter

API Jmeter create a reusable request depends on the selection of the user

Does anyone know how simulate scenario below and write on a reusable format? Your response is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Example I have this userdefine variable name "userInput" if user tries to enter these following metrics it should generate the corresponding request as well. Note variable name may varries from time to time depends on user selection.

Scenario 1 - network,cpu,process

{
"os": "Linux",
"timeOffset": "0",
"submanagerlogs": "false",
"metrics": {
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.NetworkMetric": "NetworkMetric.json",
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpukMetric": "CpukMetric.json",
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json"
},
"preDefinedAgents": {}
}

Scenario 2 - cpu,process

{
"os": "Linux",
"timeOffset": "0",
"submanagerlogs": "false",
"metrics": {
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpukMetric": "CpukMetric.json",
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json"
},
"preDefinedAgents": {}
}

Scenario 3 -network,cpu

{
"os": "Linux",
"timeOffset": "0",
"submanagerlogs": "false",
"metrics": {
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.NetworkMetric": "NetworkMetric.json",
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.CpukMetric": "CpukMetric.json"
},
"preDefinedAgents": {}
}

Scenario 4 - process

{
"os": "Linux",
"timeOffset": "0",
"submanagerlogs": "false",
"metrics": {
"com.cixsoft.agent.metric.ProcessInfoMetric": "ProcessInfoMetric.json"
},
"preDefinedAgents": {}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been given the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73138655/api-jmeter-create-a-reusable-request-depends-on-the-selection-of-the-user)

If building JSON is not what you're looking for you can use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and select this or that Sampler depending on the `${userInput}` variable value

[image]

More information: [Selection Statements in JMeter Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy)